# Calling a function and escaping it with a goto: memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, recursion, stack, goto

If I call a function, and escape it with a goto, will I be leaking onto the stack? Is that like dividing by zero? Will the universe implode in a reverse-Big-Bang?

This is not my program, but it has almost exactly the same structure...

```
bool func()
{
    blah(1337.1337);
    uber("iasouhfia");
    if(random) goto escapeLadder;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
    {
        func();
    } 
    escapeLadder:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Jumping to a label in a different function fails to compile for me.

Comment: This is not valid C++, you'll get a syntax error on `goto escapeLadder`. Is this actually plain C?

Comment: What language is that?  It looks like C, but neither C nor C++ permits a `goto` to a label in a different function.

Comment: It's C++ (mebbe I made a syntax error on the label?). Thanks, that's all I needed to know...How to delete this question? (unless, as I doubt, it may be useful to someone).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf):

*"The scope of a label is the function in which it appears."* (6.1 Labeled statement)

So, you can't `goto` to a label outside the function, hence your question contains a syntax error.

Comment: This is also true for C. Jumping outside of a function requires a C++ exception or C-style `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Answer (score 0):

first syntax is incorrect
second in right program it does not make memory leak because the is no memory allocated without free  memory